# Material UI - Change Font Size of TextField from Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, styles, material-ui, textfield

I have the following functional component and I would like to change the font size of the textfield, but for some reason I can't figure it out. I know if I have a traditional component I can export it `withStyles` and set the `className` or `InputProps`, but I'm not sure how to do that with my current setup:

Class Definition:

```
const FormObjectText = ({id, multiline, onBlur, onChange, onFocus, placeholder, value, style, ...additionalProps}) => (
    <TextField
        {...additionalProps}
        fullWidth
        id={id}
        inputProps={additionalProps.maxLength != null ? {maxLength: additionalProps.maxLength} : {}}
        margin="normal"
        multiline={multiline}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        onChange={e => onChange({ value: e.target.value })}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        style={{
            ...style
        }}
        value={value !== null ? value : ""}
    />
);
```

Export from that file:

```
export const FORM_OBJECT_DICT = {
    text: FormObjectTextStyled,
    date: FormObjectDate,
    // Others
};
```

Where it is called in another file:

```
{FORM_OBJECT_DICT["text"]({
    value: editing ? value : getFormObjectDisplayValue(configuration, value),
    onChange: this.onChange
})}
```

Firstly, is there any way to change the font size of the TextField using inline styles (not `withStyles()`), or if not, where/how would i apply `withStyles()` in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the font size with inline styles this way:

```
<TextField inputProps={{ style: { fontSize: "5rem" } }} />
```

There is nothing about `withStyles` that cares whether your component is a function component or a class, so if you want to use classes, you could do something like:

```
const FormObjectTextStyled = withStyles(styles)(FormObjectText);
```

and then access the `classes` prop inside `FormObjectText`.

Here's a sandbox showing both approaches:

[image: Edit TextField inline styles]